# Problems sending a message to a player

Tags: java, file, search

I have a problem with my bukkit plugin.
What I try to do is search through a file, and read it line by line (that works), then if the line has some text in it, it has to return that line, but it also has to return all the other lines in the file which also have that specific text in it. And when i have these lines, i have to send these lines in a message to the Player, that is not the problem, but when i send the lines i get now, the "\n" doesn't work, here is the code i use now:

```
  public String searchText(String text, String file, Player p)
    {
        String data = null;

        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String line = null;

            while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                if(line.indexOf(text) >= 0)
                {
                    data += System.getProperty("line.separator") + line + System.getProperty("line.separator");
                }
                p.sendMessage("+++++++++++GriefLog+++++++++++");
                p.sendMessage(data);
                p.sendMessage("++++++++++GriefLogEnd+++++++++");
            }

            br.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();            
        }

        return "";
    }
```

The return is meant to be empty, because the info is returned to the player a bit higher:P
The problem now is, how do i add an "\n" to the data variable, because when i use this function in the rest of my code, it gives a lot of lines, but without the "\n", so how do i put that in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your method isn't supposed to return anything, remove your return statement and set the return type to void.
It looks like your code would output the data string once for each line your search term occurs, try:

```
data = "";
while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
{
    if(line.indexOf(text) >= 0)
    {
        //remove the first System.getProperty("line.separator") if
        //you don't want a leading empty line
        data += System.getProperty("line.separator") + line + 
            System.getProperty("line.separator");
    }
}
if (data.length() > 0) {
    p.sendMessage("+++++++++++GriefLog+++++++++++");
    p.sendMessage(data);
    p.sendMessage("++++++++++GriefLogEnd+++++++++");
}
```